# angular-js uglify downloaded modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, grunt-usemin, grunt-contrib-uglify

So i have an `angular` application. With this application i have alot of plugins (modules) that i use in my app.

i am trying to minify them which actually works. However after they have been minified (uglifyed) im getting the following error:

```
failed to instantiate module app due to:
```

Due to: And then all the modules. (starting by the first loaded then moving on).

Does this mean that i am unable to minify angular modules. (which would basicly mean im stuck with a 1000 line long `HTML` file).

Comment: where is the error coming from and what is the error? Don't leave out the important parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Explicit dependency injection

   ```
   app.controller('myController',function(module1,module2){
     //...
   });
   myController.$inject=['module1','module2'];
   ```
2. Inline annotation

   ```
   app.controller('myController',['module1','module2',function(module1,module2){
     //...
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing it wrong. As the AngularJs documentation specifies, when you are going to minify your files, you must specify the dependencies like this:

```
app.controller('$ctrl', ['dep1', 'dep2', function(dep1, dep2) {
// your code here
}]);
```

This way, when the files are minified, the dependencies are not modified. See the angularJs tutorial: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification

Answer (score 0):

No, this does not mean you cannot minnify the module files. You can achieve this.

Check to make sure the order in wich they are concatenated/minnified is correct, if for example module x uses something from module y and x is loaded after y, this will show the error.

If the problem is because of the way the modules are declared, you could install **grunt-ng-annotate** wich will, when run, change all module declarations to the desired format so that you do not receive the mentioned error.

```
npm install grunt-ng-annotate --save-dev
```